# pan size and cream pull candy

Tags: candy

I am making cream pull candy. Recipe is usually made in a 4 Qt. pan. Can I use a 8 qt. pan as long as  candy thermometer is submerged enough or will the different size--e.g. more surface area  especially width-- interfere with the candy formation?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Make sure that you brush down the sides of the pan a few times with a pastry brush soaked in water before your syrup reaches the soft ball stage to make sure there's no crystalized sugar left on the sides of the pan (which will trigger recrystalization once it's melted and make your sugar grainy.) After it reaches soft ball give it a swirl every few seconds to make sure it's heating evenly. You should be good.

Good luck!